# Coding Map values to interface - Declare Map <String, List<>> and assign HashMap<String, ArrayList<>>()

Tags: java, dictionary

I use this common initialization format when I anticipate changing the implementation of the List interface at a later time:

```
List<Foo> foos = new ArrayList<Foos>();
```

In an effort to gain the same utility for the values within a Map, I attempted the following but my compiler whines about List<> and ArrayList<> being incompatible types.

```
Map<String, List<Foo>> fooMap = new HashMap<String, ArrayList<Foo>>;
```

I've been unable to find an explanation for why I cannot initialize the map in this manner and I'd like to understand the reasoning.

And, sure, this works...

```
Map<String, List<Foo>> foosMap = new HashMap<String, List<Foo>>;
// ... populate map
ArrayList<Foo> foosAryLst = (ArrayList)foosMap.get("key1");
```

... but I'm a curious castaphobe. I'd rather fix compile-time errors than runtime errors, things like this aggravate my OCD and the smell of casting conjures an odor similar to the urinal trough after free deep-fried asparagus night at the stadium.

My questions come down to:

1. Why can I not code my map values to an interface.
2. Is there a workaround that doesn't require casting?

Any input will be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: `List<Object> list = new ArrayList<String>();` won't compile. If you understand this, then you will understand why `Map<Whatever, List<AnotherWhatever>> map = new HashMap<Whatever, ArrayList<AnotherWhatever>>()` doesn't compile either.

Comment: In your first example, the assigned class implements the declared interface, but it won't compile due to the generic types mismatch -->  Interface<E> != ClassImplementingInterface<F>.   So the implication is that with Map<K,V> the generic type <V> is specifically the interface, and it doesn't consider a class which implements the interface as a match with V?

Comment: Yes. And that's not only for `V` but for any generic. Note that the rule is: `SupportingGenerics<SuperClass> foo = new SupportingGenerics<SubClass>()` won't compile.

Comment: It's not an exact duplicate but highly related: [Is List<Dog> a subclass of List<Animal>? Why aren't Java's generics implicitly polymorphic?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2745265/1065197)

Comment: Much thanks! I never made that connection. I presumed the generic match/restriction was based on just the content type of the collection, not the collection itself. And, thanks for the rule defined in code - it helped me better understand List<? extends Object> Obj = new ArrayList<String>();

Comment: One more thing: You should not declare variables like `List<? extends YourClass>` for storage, the compiler won't allow adding elements to this kind of generics.

Comment: I cannot .add() individual elements to such a list, but I can construct like List<? extends Superclass> = new ArrayList<subclass>(existingSubclassList);  Didn't know that either. Thanks again!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure, there's a workaround that doesn't require casting: don't cast; write

```
List<Foo> foosLst = foosMap.get("key1");
```

...and code to the interface with the `List` as well as the `Map`.

The root issue, though, is that a `Map<String, ArrayList<Foo>>` isn't substitutable wherever you'd use `Map<String, List<Foo>>`.  In particular,

```
Map<String, List<Foo>> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put("foo", new LinkedList<Foo>());
```

works, but not if `map` is a `Map<String, ArrayList<Foo>>`.  So one isn't a drop-in substitute for the other.

Comment: Perhaps mention wildcards?

Comment: @TomG if using wildcards, then you cannot add anything to the collection.

Comment: Thanks for the response! That answers question #2, and illustrates that I can use any class implementing the List interface within the Map. I am still a bit unclear re: inability to do Map<String, List<Foo>> fooMap = new HashMap<String, ArrayList<Foo>>; Am I missing something that makes this type of initialization pointless want?

Comment: Marked as correct answer, but Luiggi's response provided excellent clarification for question #1.    <snip> List<Object> list = new ArrayList<String>(); won't compile. If you understand this, then you will understand why Map<Whatever, List<AnotherWhatever>> map = new HashMap<Whatever, ArrayList<AnotherWhatever>>() doesn't compile either. –  Luiggi Mendoza  </snip>

Comment: @IdusOrtus: That was what I was explaining, that a `HashMap<String, ArrayList<Foo>>` cannot be used anywhere a `Map<String, List<Foo>>` can be, so you can't assign it to a variable of that type.

Comment: True, and thanks. Im sure others understood, but It didn't sink in for me until I connected the dots laid out.

Answer (score 1):

The declaration that you proposed

```
Map<String, List<Foos>> fooMap = new HashMap<String, ArrayList<Foos>>();
```

simply does not make sense: The variable `fooMap` has the type `Map<String, List<Foos>>`. This means:

- every value that you obtain from this map is a `List<Foos>`
- you may put every value into this list that is (of a subtype of) `List<Foos>`

If you wanted a map that has `ArrayList`s as its values, then you would declare it as

```
Map<String, ArrayList<Foos>> fooMap = new HashMap<String, ArrayList<Foos>>();
```

If you don't care about the list type, then you can say

```
Map<String, List<Foos>> fooMap = new HashMap<String, List<Foos>>();
```

But there's no sensible meaning of mixing the two. Even if you *could* write what you proposed, then you could still not obtain an `ArrayList` from this map, because this is simply not the type that `fooMap` was declared with.

---

In most cases,

```
Map<String, List<Foos>> fooMap = new HashMap<String, List<Foos>>();
```

should be appropriate. Depending on the use case, one could possibly go further by saying

```
Map<String, List<? extends Foos>> fooMap = new HashMap<String, List<? extends Foos>>();
```

This way, you can also put lists into the map that contain sublcasses of `Foos`, like

```
List<SpecialFoos> specialFoos = ...
fooMap.put("special", specialFoos);
```

But of course, it's up to you to decide whether this is necessary or not.

Answer (score 0):

The core of the problem is that the compiler cannot keep track of what `fooMap` may have been assigned to at any particular point in the execution of your code, so there is no way for the compiler to know that

```
fooMap.put("abc", new ArrayList<Foo>())
```

should be legal, but that

```
fooMap.put("abc", new LinkedList<Foo>())
```

should not be.

All that the compiler knows about the typing of `fooMap` is its **declared** type `Map<String, List<Foo>>`. So, it enforces that whatever object to which you assign `fooMap` must be able to support all of the operations which a generic `Map<String, List<Foo>>` is capable of executing. The second line of code above is clearly legal for a `Map<String, List<Foo>>`, but not legal for a `Map<String, ArrayList<Foo>>`, so the compiler forbids you from assigning `fooMap` to a `Map<String, ArrayList<Foo>>`.